# Were women allowed to offer korbanot on private altars?

Tags: halacha, women, korban, bamot

When private altars were permitted (heter bamot) were women allowed to offer sacrifices on them or was it similar to the temple where only men were allowed to offer the sacrifices?

Comment: This is wholly in conclusive standing alone, so it remains a comment, but the only rite of sacrifice that was valid when done by non-priests was slaughtering. The Talmud clearly allows women to perform the rite of slaughter, along with slaves and the impure: http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=zevachim&daf=32a&go=Go One could perhaps infer from this that whatever non-priests could do, *any* non-priests could do, in which case women could perform the rites on private altars.

Comment: Zevahim 14:4 says that the service was performed by the first born: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h51.htm Exodus 24:5 implies that the firstborn that did the service were were male: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0224.htm

Comment: @BabySeal [tosefta 13:8](http://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Zevahim.13) includes daughter

Comment: interesting, are we to infer from earlier in the tosefta that the daughter is a first born? in general 13:2 in light of 13:5 and 13:8 needs some clarification. Perhaps 5 and 8 could be taken to mean "they bring sacrifices" not they actually perform the rites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [חברותא](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02434.html#HtmpReportNum0014_L5) women were allowed to offer korbanot on private altars.

> זר, (33) **אשה** (34), עבד (35), עובדים בבמה, וכן שאר פסולי כהונה, כאונן (36), יושב (37), שאינו רחוץ ידים ורגלים (38), שתויי יין (39) ומחוסר בגדים (40), **כשרים בבמה**. ‏

Unfortunately the online version does not have the sources.

Comment: Where is Chavrusa is this stated?

Comment: @mevaqesh: It's in חברותא - זבחים in the section (appendix?) at the end titled נספח - דיני במה - at the [link](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02434.html#HtmpReportNum0014_L5) I provided - http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02434.html#HtmpReportNum0014_L5